# What kind of server do I have to use?

Tags: asynchronous

I want to code an application quite basic:

A client sends a JSON formated string to a server that asynchronously publish it.

I mean, all the clients will also get the JSON as soon as the server publishes it.

My question is about:

- What kind of server to use (I basically only know a bit about web services and servlets)
- Where can I host and run the resulting code ? I guess it won't be free, of course.

Sorry if the question seems a bit too wide or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Python or ruby are well suited for creating such servers
- A simple solution is to host an app on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)